# On support of distributions in ${\cal D'}(\Omega)$.

Tags: distribution-theory

First some definitions. $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb R^N$.

1. ${\cal D}(\Omega)$ denotes the set of all compactly supported smooth functions, $f \in {\cal C}^\infty_0(\Omega)$, equipped with the following convergence notion:

> $ {\cal C}^\infty_0(\Omega) \ni \{ f_n \}_{n \in \mathbb N} \overset {n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} f \in {\cal C}^\infty_0(\Omega) $ if:
>
> - $\exists K \subset \Omega$ compact $\ |$ ${\rm supp}(f_n) \subseteq K \quad \forall n$
> - $\partial^\alpha f_n \rightrightarrows \partial^\alpha f $ uniformly, $\forall \alpha $ multiindex.

2. a linear functional $u: {\cal D}(\Omega) \to \mathbb C $ is a **distribution** if $\forall$ convergent sequence $ \{f_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N} \in {\cal D}(\Omega)$ one has:
   $$\lim_n u(f_n) = u (\lim_n f_n)$$

${\cal D}' (\Omega) \equiv \{ u: {\cal D}(\Omega) \to \mathbb C \ | \ u 
 $ is a distribution$\}$

3. given $\Omega_0 \subset \Omega $, $\Omega_0$ is said to be a *vanishing open set* for $u \in {\cal D}'(\Omega) $ if $\forall f \in {\cal D}(\Omega) $ such that ${\rm supp} f \subseteq \Omega_0$, one has:
   $$u(f) =0$$

4.$ \forall u \in {\cal D}'(\Omega) $ we define ${\rm supp } \ u \equiv \Omega \setminus \bigcup\limits^{}_{i} \Omega_0^i$, with $\Omega_0^i$ a vanishing open set for $u$.

---

**Question**: is ${\rm supp} \ u $ compact $\forall u \in {\cal D}'(\Omega) $?

Comment: Since $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb R^N$, which is finite-dimensional, maybe we could apply *Heine-Borel theorem*: $\Omega$ is compact $\iff$ $\Omega$ is closed and bounded.
It's closed by definition, as a complementary set of a union of open sets which is open, but I'm not sure about boundedness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there are distributions with non-compact support. An example is a pulse train:
$$
u = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \delta_k,
$$
where $\delta_k$ is a Dirac delta supported at $x=k$. Less exotic examples come from non-compactly supported functions in $L^1_{loc}$.

Comment: Is ${\rm supp } \ u \equiv \mathbb Z$ in this case?

Comment: Yes, that’s correct.

Comment: Another example is $u(f):=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \, dx.$ It has all of $\mathbb{R}$ as support.